# How to take a 2D view of Boost.MultiArray as an argument into function?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, type-inference, boost-multi-array

I have a 3D array of `double`s. I want to write simple & generic function to print 2D slices of it.

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

template<class M> // any model of MultiArray concept
void printFloatMatrix(typename M::template array_view<2u>::type matrix) {
    using std::printf;

    for(auto& row : matrix) {
        for(auto& elem : row) {
            printf("%5.3f ", elem);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main() {
    typedef boost::multi_array<double,3> data_t;
    data_t test_matrix{data_t::extent_gen()[10][10][2]};
    // ...

    using boost::indices;
    using boost::multi_array_types::index_range;
    printFloatMatrix(test_matrix[ indices[index_range()] [index_range()] [0] ]);
}
```

With GCC this produces the error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:24:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘printFloatMatrix(boost::multi_array_ref<double, 3u>::array_view<2u>::type)’
test.cpp:24:79: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:5:6: note: template<class M> void printFloatMatrix(typename M::array_view<2u>::type)
```

Why the error?

Why doesn't `M` is inferred to be `boost::multi_array_ref<double, 3u>`?

How do I write the prototype that'd work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to spell the exact reason why C++ type inference fails here, but changing the function prototype to `template<class M> void printFloatMatrix(const M& matrix)` worked.

The prototype is uselessly wide now, though. With high chance it will bite me in the future. This situation will hopefully be fixed with the advent of concepts, or can alternatively be worked-around with static asserts.

Thanks to `##c++` at Freenode.

Comment: Any time you have `typename X::Y`, you got a so called "non-deducible context", meaning that no template arguments can be inferred from the passed argument for that parameter. You either need to specify the type at the call site, change that non-deducible context (like you did here), or provide another parameter that allows template argument deduction.

Comment: That must be related to the turing-completeness of templates and the halting problem. Thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you have to constrain your arguments:

```
template<class M,
  std::enable_if_t<M::dimensionality == 2 and std::is_same_v<typename M::element, double>, int> =0
> 
void printFloatMatrix(const M& matrix)
```